# Excel - Convert Number to Text Based on Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I convert a number to Text in Excel based on what the number is.

For eg, I have the following logic to be implemented:

```
pob > 1 ? "Strong Buy" : pob > 0 ? "Buy" : pob < -1 ? "Strong Sell" : pob < 0 ? "Sell" : "Neutral"
```

Column A has values 0, 1, 2, -1
In Column B, I have to replace these numbers with the following words.

```
0 = Neutral
1 = Buy
2 = Strong Buy
-1 = Sell
-2 = Strong Sell
```

How do I do this in Excel?

Comment: Create a small range/table that has the key/value pairs and use a VLOOKUP to find the text for the associated number, simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XLOOKUP()` could be a perfect function for this case. Try-

```
=XLOOKUP(A1,{-2,-1,0,1,2},{"Strong Sell","Sell","Neutral","Buy","Strong Buy"},"",-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it. Put in cell: `B1` the following formula:

```
=LET(set, A1:A14, CONV, LAMBDA(x, SWITCH(x, -2, "Strong Sell",-1, "Sell", 
  0, "Neutral", 1, "Buy",2, "Strong Buy", "CASE NOT DEFINED")),
 MAP(set, LAMBDA(x, CONV(x))))
```

Using `SWITCH` via user `LAMBDA` function `CONV` and `MAP` function, **it doesn't require to drag-down the formula**. The result is returned in one array. In case the number was not defined it returns: `CASE NOT DEFINED`. The `LET` function is used for easier reading and composition.

Here is the output using the sample data provided by @Harun24hr:

[image: sample excel file]

Comment: I think the range function is overkill. It seems that `=SWITCH(A1, -2, "Strong Sell",-1, "Sell", 0,"Neutral", 1, "Buy",2, "Strong Buy", "CASE NOT DEFINED")` works just fine to answer this question.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for the feedback, quick question, what do you mean by "range function"? yes, I was trying to answer this question. The OP didn't provide logical conditions that make me think in other options like `IFS` for example. For this case it is just enough to use `SWITCH`. Just a small number of financial actions, so it is not expected to have more options to think on a translation table or lookup table. `SWITCH` has a limit of `127` possible values it is enough for this case. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant "array" function.